# Extract a List of .zip files into one new directory each, directory name to be taken from name of the zip file

Tags: files, zip

I have a folder containing many `.zip` files. They are named like this:

```
John-Rupert A. Doe_nnnnnnn_assignsubmission_file_*.zip
```

where `n` is a digit, `*` is a string and `John-Rupert A. Doe` is a string that may contain spaces, dots and dashes.

For each of them, I want to do the following:

1. create a directory. I do this via:

   ```
   ls | cut -d'_' -f 1 | sed 's/ //g' | tr -d '.' | tr -d '-' | xargs -L 1 mkdir
   ```

   (So, the corresponding directory name for the example above would be `JohnRupertADoe`)
2. Now I want to extract each `.zip` file into the directory created using this `.zip` file name. But how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with:

```
for z in ./*.zip
do name="${z%%_*}"; dest=".${name//[ .-]/}"; mkdir "$dest"; unzip "$z" -d "$dest"
done
```

For each `z`ip file it extracts the name part ( `${z%%_*}` deletes suffix greedily) it then removes any occurrence of dot, dash and space (`${name//[ .-]/}`) and passes the resulting string as an argument to `mkdir` to create the corresponding directory. It then unzips the archive to the specified `d`estination.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
for i in *.zip; do
  zipdir() { echo "$i" | cut -d'_' -f 1 | sed 's/ //g' | tr -d '.' | tr -d '-'; }
  zipdir | xargs -L 1 mkdir
  mv "$i" "$(zipdir)"/
done
```

Or to remove both `tr` pipes, you could just add to your pipe to `sed` (also untested):

```
for i in *.zip; do
  zipdir() { echo "$i" | cut -d'_' -f 1 | sed 's/ //g;s/.//g;s/-//g'; }
  zipdir | xargs -L 1 mkdir
  mv "$i" "$(zipdir)"/
done
```

Comment: `tr -d ' .-'` works too, to delete spaces, dots and dashes.  or `sed 's/[- .]//g'`

Comment: I thought on many systems, `tr -d` could only take a single character as an argument...was I completely wrong in thinking this???

Comment: not to my knowledge.  afaik, `tr` always works on sets of characters.

Comment: Very good to know.  Thanks.  Maybe I had it confused with the fact that I normally use it with single characters for *replacement/substitution* since results can get a little crazy if multiple characters are involved in that type of scenario.