# unpacking recursively all xlsx files into a new directory containing of the original files name

Tags: bash, find

I have a bunch of excel files I would like to extract recursively from all subdirectories, keeping the directory/file name as the new directory name for all extracted files of each xlsx.

to extract a file I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244636/extract-a-list-of-zip-files-into-one-new-directory-each-directory-name-to-be-t). Unfortunately my bash knowledge lacks the skill to so all in one command.

So I tried to split it up in smaller parts first:

```
for z in ./*
do name="${z%%_*}"; dest=".${name//[ .-]/}"; mkdir "$dest";
done
```

if I try that the `*` in

```
for z in ./*
```

searches for all files in the current directory and not like I had anticipated the result from

`find . -name "*.xlsx"`

so I tried if I could maybe reverse it:

`for f in | find . -name "*.xlsx"; do d="${f}"; mkdir -p "$d"`

but it obviously doesn't work cause my piping is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if your split with `bash` is right.

Because I have stopped working with bash a long time ago.

But when you want the output of find in a loop, try this :

```
find . -name '*.xlsx' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' z; do
        name="${z%%_*}" 
        dest=".${name//[ .-]/}" 
        mkdir "$dest"
    done
```

Comment: You can also just do:

    `for i in $( find . -name '*.xlsx' )`. But you could run into issues if your filenames and/or directory names have spaces in them.

Comment: guided me into the right direction